# Cast to string failed for value "{ _id: 5bd587cffb6fc074abb12cb8,\n name: \'name 2\',\n year: \'4\',\n id: \'102\' }" at path "winner"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My database collection:

winners:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd58921fb6fc074abb12ce8"
    },
    "id": "301",
    "winner": [
        "101",
        "102"
    ]
}
```

Winner model is here

```
var winner = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  id: String,
  winner:[ String ]
},
  {
  strict: false
});
var Winner = mongoose.model('winner', winner);
```

**the values 101 and 102 in the winner array in winner collection should be updated with {"sample":"data"}**

```
 var result = [{"id": "101" },{"id": "102" }];
 var length = result.length;
 for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
  {
  Winner.updateMany(
    { "winner" : result[i].id },
    { $set: { "winner" : result[i] } }, function (err,output) {
      if(err) 
      {
      console.log(err);
      }
      else
      {
      console.log(output);
      }
    }
 );
}
```

Expected output :

The winner collection should be updated to

winners:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd58921fb6fc074abb12ce8"
    },
    "id": "301",
    "winner": [
        {"sample":"data"},
        {"sample":"data"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

At first you're inserting array of strings but later you want to store array of objects. Mongoose schema will not allow that. You will have to update your schema from `winner:[ String ]` to `winner:[{sample: String}]` and store array of objects in first place.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd58921fb6fc074abb12ce8"
    },
    "id": "301",
    "winner": [
        {"sample": "101"},
        {"sample": "102"}
    ]
}
```

Edit: Also you want to update

```
Winner.updateMany(
    { "winner" : result[i].id },
    { $set: { "winner" : result[i] } },
.
.
```

to

```
Winner.updateMany(
    { "winner.sample" : result[i].id },
    { $set: { "winner" : result[i] } },
.
.
```

Comment: it returns null when checking conditon like this `{ "winner.sample" : result[i].id }` , since the data 101 is present in winner[0] and not in winner.sample and i this $set should be changed to `{ $set: { "winner.sample" : result[i] } }` once the scheme is changed

Comment: but even if i change i get this error `Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got 101`

Comment: can you try changing your schema and drop your collection then insert/update document ?

Answer (score 1):

Update Many is used to update multiple documents not multiple values in a single document. In your case what you need to do is..

```
find winner collection of your and store it to variable `winners`

winners.winner = winners.winner.reduce((acc, value) => {
    acc.push({"data": value})
    return acc;
}, []);

winners.save();
```

Comment: whats that reduce ?? @aninalous